# On precision in multiplying integers stored as doubles

Tags: floating-point, precision, ieee-754

I have code like this:

```
double x = ...;
double y = ...;
double z = x * y;
```

Suppose x and y are assigned to integers (say, double x = 6, double y = 5), and x * y fits into 48 bits. Am I guaranteed that `z` will not loose precision? In other words, that `z - floor(z) == 0.0` ?

Assume the compiler uses IEEE-754 standard, and double uses 64 bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are guaranteed not to lose precision. The basic rule of floating point is, the result is computed exactly, and then stored as closely as possible. Since all integers up to 2^53 are exactly representable, `z` will be exact.

Comment: >The basic rule of floating point is, the result is computed exactly. Wow, that's interesting. Is it true for any operation? Division, multiplication, addition, pow, etc?

Comment: @Evgenii.Balai: It is true for the elementary operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division. For the library routines such as `pow`, `sin`, `log`, and so on, the IEEE 754-2008 standard recommends that should be true, but, to my knowledge, nobody has implemented all of them with a known-bound run time. Quality of implementations varies from vendor to vender. Generally they return results with a small error.